# Kotlin reflect proguard SmallSortedMap

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, proguard, kotlin-reflect

```
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$data$1: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$data$1: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EntrySet
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry
Warning: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry: can't find referenced class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry
```

I'm getting these warnings which break my release build on the task `transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForAppRelease`.

I know I can just ignore the warnings or inform proguard to not warn by using `-dontwarn` but I was wondering if anyone else had come across this and had actually found the correct fix.

I'm using Kotlin version `1.1.4-2`

Comment: I didn't found another fix then add -dontwarn to my proguard file. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope :( I really hope it gets fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting Alexander Udalov from issue [KT-7652](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7652#comment=27-993857):

> In any way, reflection failures when `kotlin.*`  is obfuscated are expected at the moment. What we can do is work on a useful set of rules for proguard to minimize the binary size of the reflection library.

So there is no correct fix at the moment.